# How to properly use a default value in Kendo Grid MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This builds upon my previous thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461208/kendo-grid-popup-not-firing-when-add-new-record-is-clicked). Please visit the thread for some posted reference code and problem overview.

My new issue is: I am using a default value for the Kendo grid to overcome the previous issue. However, when I click "Update" to create the new record, the FemaleCategoryKey field says "null", and the ModelState.IsValid is false, so the new record is never saved to the database. 
[image].

The new code for the Kendo grid looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<com.RomanceCoachOnTheGo.MVC.Models.FemaleAdvice>()
.Name("FemaleAdvice")
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Create();
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Model(item => { item.Id(m => m.FemaleAdviceKey); item.Field(m => m.Category).DefaultValue(new com.RomanceCoachOnTheGo.MVC.Models.FemaleCategory() { FemaleCategoryKey = 1 }); })
.Create(c => c.Action("CreateFemaleAdvice", "Administrator"))
            .Read(r => r.Action("ReadFemaleAdvice", "Administrator"))
            .Update(u => u.Action("UpdateFemaleAdvice", "Administrator"))
            .Destroy(d => d.Action("DeleteFemaleAdvice", "Administrator"))
        )
.Columns(col =>
            {
                col.Bound(c => c.FemaleCategoryKey).ClientTemplate("#= Category.Title #");
                col.Bound(c => c.Title);
                col.Bound(c => c.Description);
                col.Bound(c => c.Body);
                col.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
            })
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()

    .Filterable()
)
```

How do I properly use .DefaultValue to get this to work? Or is my issue somewhere else?